# Passo a Passo com javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço um Step-by-step em JavaScript. Esse é o
[Modelo que preciso](https://www.printi.com.br/configuracao-cartao-de-visita) para ir montando um cartão de visita...
Preciso para montar uma foto para túmulo...
[Meu modelo](http://placasparatumulo.com.br/categoria/2/fotos-porcelanas)

Comment: Segue um framework Jquery: http://www.jquery-steps.com/

Comment: Exemplos, https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/e3MBM   -   
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/step-wizard-working

Comment: não é bem isso... :D a cada seleção o input radio joga para a proxima opção